# Int32.TryParse() returns zero on failure - success or failure?

Tags: c#, .net, int

I read this from msdn about `Int32.TryParse()`

> When this method returns, contains the
>   32-bit signed integer value equivalent
>   to the number contained in s, if the
>   conversion succeeded, or zero if the
>   conversion failed.

But what happens if the passed string itself is a string representation of '0'. So the `TryParse` will return zero. How can I know if it is a success or a failure?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

No, `TryParse` *returns* true or false to indicate success. The value of the `out` parameter is used for the parsed value, or 0 on failure. So:

```
int value;
if (Int32.TryParse(someText, out value))
{
    // Parse successful. value can be any integer
}
else
{
    // Parse failed. value will be 0.
}
```

So if you pass in "0", it will execute the first block, whereas if you pass in "bad number" it will execute the second block.

Comment: Gosh! My bad. I should close SO while I'm programming. Its too easy to post here :).

Comment: You left out a `)` at the end of your if.</nitpick>

Answer (score 6):

The method returns a boolean indicating success or failure. Use that. The integer is a reference parameter passed into the method, and has nothing to do with the return value of the method.

Here's the prototype of `Int32.TryParse()` from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx). It's very clear that it *returns* a boolean. The second parameter is an `out int` which means that argument is passed by reference, so it will be mutated by the method.

```
public static bool TryParse(
    string s,
    out int result
)
```

So to check success or failure, do this:

```
int value;

if (Int32.TryParse("0", out value))
    Console.WriteLine("Parsed as " + value);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Could not parse");
```

Answer (score 3):

TryParse() returns a Boolean.

```
        Int32 testInt;

        if (!Int32.TryParse("123", out testInt))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Is not a Int32!");
            return; // abbrechen
        }

        MessageBox.Show("The parst Int32-value is " + testInt);
```

Answer (score 3):

using C# 7 now you can declare the variable within the TryParse like ...

```
if (Int32.TryParse(someText, out int value))
{
   // Parse successful. value can be any integer
}
else
{
   // Parse failed. value will be 0.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Int32.TryParse()` method returns a `boolean` value as return and provides the converted value as an out parameter. So you can check for the return `boolean` value for the status.

```
private static void TryToParse(string value)
   {
      int number;
      bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
      if (result)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);         
      }
      else
      {
         if (value == null) value = ""; 
         Console.WriteLine("Attempted conversion of '{0}' failed.", value);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

My favorite and shortest;

```
int number = Int32.TryParse(TheValueToConvert, out int n) ? n : 0;
```

Returns the converted integer, otherwise `0`